# Parse an object and add a member property to each member

Tags: object, powershell

I have an object which looks for example like this

```
Name      Number
----      ------
John      one
Major     two
Mars      one
```

I want to go through each member and check on Number and add a property that in the end it looks like this.

```
Name      Number     IsItOne
----      ------     -------
John      one        True
Major     two        False
Mars      one        True
```

What I got so far is do a foreach loop through the object but then I have two objects and have no chance as far as I know to change the original object.

Comment: Are you talking about an object or set of objects? It looks like you have three objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be like you are talking about a set of objects with properties `Name` and `Number`.

If so, you can do like this:

```
$a | %{  $isitone = $false; if($_.Number -eq "one") {$isitone=$true} $_ | 
         add-member -Type noteproperty -name IsItOne -value $isitone  }
```

Comment: Thats the trick, thanks. Love how this is 10 times more elegant than the work around I was trying to do :)

Answer (score 4):

Just another (shorter) version:

```
$obj | add-member -type scriptproperty -name IsItOne -value {$this.Number -eq 'one'} -passthru
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible alternative.

```
function new-stuff ($name, $number) {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{name=$name; number=$number}
}

$(
    new-stuff John  one
    new-stuff Major two
    new-stuff Mars  one
) | ForEach { $_ | Add-Member -PassThru ScriptProperty IsItOne {$this.Number-eq"one"} }
```